# Not able to retrieve company name from MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to retrieve the company name and store it in a session in CodeIgniter but I'm unable to retrieve the company fields from the table pr_users_details.

`row1->company` should have given me the company name but it's not.

```
<?php
Array
(
[session_id] => ed64aacc3975c359615569ff9c0bedb1
[ip_address] => ::1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
[last_activity] => 1493791463
[user_data] => 
[is_admin_logged_in] => 1
[admin_user_name] => admin@google.com
[admin_userpass] => 65e1b655a6d6f4cbed20554d3b52521a743afdc0
[admin_id] => 23
[admin_lastlogin] => 03-05-2017 07:30:37
[admin_lastloginip] => ::1
[lastrefresh] => 1493791470
[company] => 
)
?>
```

Here the company does not have a value

```
function check_admin_login()
{

    $this->db->where('username', trim($this->input->post('username')));
    $this->db->where('userpass ', sha1(trim($this->input->post('userpass'))));
    $this->db->where('status', '1');
    $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users']);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
        $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage,company');
        //$query1 = $this->db->query("Select * from pr_users_details where userid = '".$row->id."'");
        $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
        $row1 = $query1->row();
        $newdata = array(
            'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
            'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
            'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
            'admin_id' => $row->id,
            'admin_lastlogin' => date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $row->lastlogin),
            'admin_lastloginip' => $row->lastloginip,
            'lastrefresh' => time(),
            'company' => $row1->company
        );
        $company = $row1->company;
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        $companyName = $this->session->userdata('company');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        echo "</pre>";
        die;

        $this->update_admin_login_time($this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
        $this->admin_init_elements->set_global_user($row->username, $row->userpass);
        if ($this->input->post('remember')) {
            $cookie = array('name' => 'username', 'value' => $row->username, 'expire' => time() + 7600, 'secure' => false);
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        }
        $name = $row1->firstname . ' ' . $row1->lastname;
        $cookie1 = array('name' => 'name', 'value' => $name, 'expire' => time() + 7600, 'secure' => false);
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1);
        $cookie2 = array('name' => 'image', 'value' => $row1->profileimage, 'expire' => time() + 7600, 'secure' => false);
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie2);


        return 'Login Successful';
    } else {
        return 'Incorrect Username or Password.';
    }

}
```

When  printing the session I get this:

[image]

Comment: "*but its not."* - care to elaborate? Do you get an error message, or is the rest of the data there, just not the company name?

Comment: Also: Please improve the formatting of your code. Reduce the excessive indending so no horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Comment: done , thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `print_r($row1)` and post data

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check in your database table that user has a company name because I saw the table there are lots of company name fields are empty.

If there are data then try the below code:

$row1[0]->company;

Comment: added all fields and tried $row1[0]->company; still not working

Comment: are you sure there are a company name  for this query? Could you please try  $this->db->last_query() after your 2nd query and see what is your real query and run this query in your database then see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to apply your Debug skills. You can debug your code as below:

Firstly you can check by applying static company name as below:

```
$newdata = array(
            'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
            'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
            'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
            'admin_id' => $row->id,
            'admin_lastlogin' => date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $row->lastlogin),
            'admin_lastloginip' => $row->lastloginip,
            'lastrefresh' => time(),
            'company' => 'static_abc_company'
        );
```

Now if you are able to retrieve it in session then there is a problem with your DB query/data so you can print data fetched by DB query as below and check:

```
 $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
        $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage,company');
        //$query1 = $this->db->query("Select * from pr_users_details where userid = '".$row->id."'");
        $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
        $row1 = $query1->row(); 
        print_r($row1->result_array);
```

If you do not see data for company from database, check with data in DB.